# Forward user isp instead of the servers I am calling from

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I am using node express server with axios and request for the api calls for my back end to proxy the requests, but I would like to send the users details instead of the servers.

For example:

My website -> user clicks on the picture -> get is being called to my server A -> server calls another server B to retrieve data.

Now the B server will see the A's servers info, like ip, geo, isp etc. How do I forward users data like that to the A server so the B server thinks the user called this server directly from the website?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's first key to understand a lot of the information you're referring to "geo" and "isp" are all derived from the IP address itself; so what you're looking to do is forward that.

You have not included a lot of information about your setup, however I have included two possible setups.

**1. Reverse Proxy**

Server A is a reverse proxy, that proxies all requests to Server B using `nginx` - if this is the case, then we would use `Forwarded header` which is described very well [here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/forwarded/).

Example Code Snippet:

```
  location / {
    proxy_set_header  Host $host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass        http://server_b;
  }
```

**2. Application Layer**
Server A hosts a website (or other application) that sends a request in the backend to Server B.

In this event, without knowing the exact workings of the application - I would suggest you include the visitors IP in the request payload somehow.

Basic example, if you were using PHP on Server A (and this form was submitted to Server A before being passed to Server B):
`<input type="hidden" id="visitorIP" name="visitorIP" value="<?php $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']?>">`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I actually posted on another stacks community https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65570403/forward-client-header-isp-geo-to-the-server-via-proxy?noredirect=1#comment115931300_65570403 with more details included. I have the same setup for the nginx but that is not working. Users ip is added to the header but the server B in this case still detects that the request is coming from the proxy server

Comment: To confirm, on your web "application" you are looking at the 'X-Forwarded-For' header - for example in PHP ```<?php $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']?>``` (instead of just expecting the source IP to be spoofed - which is incorrect.)